# Android 9+ device misses icon on application in heads-up notification

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

**TL;DR**: Firebase cloud message does not show the icon of my application in "**heads-up**" notification only at Android 9+ devices.
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/notifications#Heads-up

Longer version:

When I send a cloud message directly from Firebase or by any Rest Client to the https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send endpoint everything looks fine, the message shows up at the screen with a title, description and icon, device makes a sound, it disappears in a while but stays in the notification bar and notification drawer.

Everything works fine until the message is delivered to a device that runs on Android 10 or 9 (but not all of them). Notification bar and notification drawer works fine and the message itself looks exactly the same as in older Android versions.
BUT the heads-up misses the icon of my application. Until now I have not been sending any "icon" with payload to Firebase, but even when I set the "icon" property with a URL to my icon, it still does not appear at the heads-up. I have put the same URL in an "image" property and then the image appears in the heads-up, but I believe it is not the property that should be used to show the application icon in the notification.

Has anybody noticed the same issue? I tried to look in the Google Android documentation - but it looks like out of date and ends with Android 8. I tried Firebase documentation but it says that "icon" property is optional (this is why I have not attached it).

I have tested notifications at:

- Android device: 5.1(works), 7(works), 8.1(works), 9(**works!**), another 9(**does not work**), 10(does not work)
- emulator of android: 8.1(works), 9(does not work), 10(does not work).

Payload is just:

```
{
    "to": "(...)",
    "notification": {
        "title": "Push from RestClient",
        "body": "Notification body"
    },
    "data": {}
}
```

Of course I have added the required by Firebase  for default_notification_icon, color and channel. This is not a solution here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add FCM metadata in your manifest.xml

```
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_icon"
        android:resource="@drawable/ic_logo_white" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_color"
        android:resource="@color/app_theme_blue" />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.firebase.messaging.default_notification_channel_id"
        android:value="@string/default_notification_channel_id" />
```

Comment: I have the metadata you mention in your comment. This is not a solution for my issue.